# VB.Net - Userform - Run Macro at set intervals

Tags: vb.net, userform

I have a Userform that runs some SQL queries and displays the row counts, it currently runs via a button. After X minutes, I want it to automatically run again - without me needing to press the button again.

I've been looking around but I can't find anything that suits my needs.

In standard VBA, I can simply use: Application.OnTime("Run_Macro", Now + #12:02:00#) at the end of the macro, and it sets the macro to run two minutes from now automatically - I am looking for the equivalent in VB.Net.

Thank you.

Comment: I think, the timer-control will be your friend.

Comment: I've enabled it, set the timer to 1 minute (60,000 miliseconds), and used Timer1.Start() - nothing happens after 1 minute. I have a "Last Updated" field - and that stays unchanged.

Comment: Is your timer calling your method, or attempting to click the button? Are you sure your timer is firing? Reduce the time interval and debug, or update a label each time it fires so that you can see that it is firing.

Comment: Did you handle the [Tick()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer.tick?view=netframework-4.8) event of your Timer control?  Double click it to get the method stub...

Comment: Just for the record, the WinForms `Timer` is not a control.  Only classes that inherit `Control` are controls.  It is a component, which is all that is required to be used in the designer.  Controls are specialised components.

Comment: Thanks for all of your comments - I've checked all of this and turns out I had overlooked the Enabled field, despite checking it previously.

Answer (score 0):

Doy. I didn't enable the Timer as I thought I had done.

Under Properties window for the Timer Control, I switched Enabled to True - I thought I had already done this.

Thanks to you guys for your help, everything else I had done was correct - it's odd how this isn't enabled by default.